# What's the difference between regular component styles and :host nested styles?

Tags: angular, css-selectors, angular6

Consider the following component-level style for a component with the default view encapsulation value of `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`:

```css
:host h2 {
    color: red;
}
```

This will compile into the following CSS:

```css
[_nghost-c0] h2[_ngcontent-c0] {
    color: red;
}
```

If you omit the `:host` selector in the rule, however, your generated CSS will be this:

```css
h2[_ngcontent-c0] {
    color: red;
}
```

Is there a behavioral difference between these two CSS rules? I understand using `:host` *itself* to style the top-level component element, but as soon as you nest to child elements, isn't `:host` pointless?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:host` is only needed when styling your component itself. You don't need to use it when creating selectors for the content within it.

If you add it to that rule (`:host h2`), you just increase the [specificity](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#specificity) of the rule (in case you need to do that). `[_nghost-c0] h2[_ngcontent-c0]` is more specific than `h2[_ngcontent-c0]` when calculating the order in which the CSS is applied.